# SPF declared as "hard fail" then what?

Tags: spf

I have question about how email authentication relies on SPF record:

- If SPF declared as "hard fail", what should be done?
- If SPF declared as "soft fail", what's the difference?

Please briefly explain whether an email is delivered to recipient or not when SPF is "hard fail". If the email is delivered on which folder it arrives, spam or inbox?

Answer (score 1):

The *Sender Policy Framework* (SPF) only designates what the sender thinks you should do to the mail. The actual outcome depends on the configuration on the receiving sender and cannot be predicted globally. The main difference between `- Fail` i.e. *hard fail* and `~ SoftFail` is that while both are NOT being allowed, soft fail is in transition. See [SPF Record Syntax](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax).

While the *hard fails* could be rejected, *soft fails* are intended to be accepted but marked as a not being allowed. In practice, the *marked* could mean e.g. flagging as spam, adding `[SPAM]` or `[SPFFAIL]` to the subject, adding a warning in the beginning of the message, or moving the message to another mailbox like Spam. SPF doesn't specify the exact action to be taken.

Your question would be off-topic on Server Fault unless you are the one who

- makes the decision on what actions should be done
- configures this to the receiving mail server
- struggles between whether to use `-` or `~` in your SPF  record.

Comment: • But receiver is unknown and not any control of reciever's mail server

Comment: Then the answer is that there's no way to know for sure. Also, even a mail passing SPF may get rejected, marked as spam, or moved to another folder for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

SPF softfail is a weak statement that the host is probably not authorized. SPF softfail can be interpreted in DMARC as either pass or fail, depending on how you set up DMARC on your email server. In [OpenDMARC](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/), SPF softfail is interpreted in DMARC as fail by default.

SPF fail, also known as SPF hardfail, is an explicit statement that the client is not authorized to use the domain in the given identity. SPF fail is definitively interpreted in DMARC as fail, regardless of the DMARC package you are using.

If DMARC is set up and you get a softfail or hardfail, where the email lands is subject to the DMARC policy: it goes to inbox if p=none, spam if p=quarantine, and rejected if p=reject.

This post covers the topic in detail: [Why SPF Authentication Fails: none, neutral, fail(hard fail), soft fail, temperror, and permerror Explained](https://dmarcly.com/blog/why-spf-authentication-fails-none-neutral-fail-hard-fail-soft-fail-temperror-and-permerror-explained)